# Nextjs Routing: Do I have to use a custom 404 page?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

Using express alone, I can create a server with custom routes and if the reqested url doesn't exist, `server.get("*", (req, res)` is the route that will be used. Now using nextjs I have a similar thing,

```
//... the basic routes
server.use('/', index)
server.use('/view', view)
server.use('/edit', edit)

server.use((err, req, res, next) =>
{
    const { status = 500, message = "Something Went Wrong" } = err
    res.status(status).send(message)
})

server.get("*", (req, res, next) =>
{
    return handle(req, res)
})
```

but the 404 (not found) request is not the only one that goes through the `*` route, so as a result nextjs displays the built-in 404 page. I can replace it with my own one by placing a 404.js component inside the pages folder. I want to have more controll over what happens when there is a 404 request. I usually use an error middleware before the `*` last route, so this means that there are no front-end / db erros anymore. How can I avoid using a custom 404 page and get more controll over the final 404 border?

Comment: _"use an error middleware before the * last route, so this means that there are no front-end / db erros anymore"_ - any reason why you couldn't do the same in your custom server with Next.js?

Comment: @juliomalves every request goes through the * path it is the default *last middleware* for everything, even for the 404 not found request. A better question for this would be: How can I check in any route if the request is a 404 not found one?